# How to read, write content to text file using FileWriter and BufferedWriter in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I have a basic requirement of writing some text into a text file and read that text and print in Console.

What is the better approach? Is anything better(in terms of performance/usage) than BufferedReader or BufferedWriter for writing and reading simple text?

Can someone also suggest better way of writing the below code aswell:

```
public class FileReadWrite 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        File objFile=new File("SampFile.txt");

        if(!objFile.exists())
            objFile.createNewFile();

        FileReader objFR=new FileReader(objFile);
        BufferedReader objBR=new BufferedReader(objFR);

        FileWriter objFW=new FileWriter(objFile);
        BufferedWriter objBW=new BufferedWriter(objFW);


        objBW.write("Hello World!!!");
        objBW.write("How Are you");
        objBW.close();

        String strContent;
        while((strContent=objBR.readLine())!=null)
            System.out.println(objBR.readLine());

        objBR.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by better way? What is your requirement?
Is there any problem that you are facing with the current Approach?

Comment: The above code is not printing the text in console, but the file is created and writing the text into that file. Why the readLine method is not reading the text and printing on the console?

Comment: You should add the problem to your question (your comment should be in the question).

Answer (score 2):

try printing the string you are reading in your while loop:

```
while((strContent=objBR.readLine())!=null)
        System.out.println(strContent);
```

Comment: Forgot about that var. Printing variable solved my problem. But do we need to use both FileWriter and BufferedWrite to write the content into file? Why BufferedWriter doesnt support File object directly? Is the above code is better one else anyother stream or method performs better?

Comment: No you can use a FileWriter alone too. Thought this way you dont have a buffered writing. So lets say you got a for loop with 100 writes, your harddisk is accessed 100 times. Select the question as solved if you dont have any problems please.